# Create a new stacking context on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable list of elements, each element of the list has a bouncing animation on click (I simplified the below example with an *enlarging* transition on hover).

If the parent container isn't scrollable, there are no problems since `overflow-x` works as expected only when `overflow-y` is set to something different than `auto` or `scroll`, as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue).

**Desired behaviour**

When the animation exceeds the boundaries of the scrollable container, it should create a new stacking context and overlap the y-axis scrollbar. It **should not** show a horizontal scrollbar.

**What I tried so far**

So far I tried:

- Using `position: absolute` on hover. It doesn't work because we are inside a scrollable container
- Applying an intermediate div with `overflow-x: visible`. It doesn't work for the same reason

I understood that I can't solve this problem if I won't be able to create a new stacking context on the fly, when the user hovers an item of the list.

Here is an example of the problem:

```css
.scrollable-div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.grow-on-hover {
  width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: royalblue;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grow-on-hover:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gold;
}

.grow-on-hover:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-div">
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

---

**Edit**:

What should happen on hover is the following effect:

[image]

Comment: you can approximate this using position:fixed : https://jsfiddle.net/j6r0mx7a/ but it won't be good for all the elements

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="scrollable-div">
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scrollable-div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.grow-on-hover {
  width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: royalblue;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grow-on-hover:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gold;
}

.grow-on-hover:hover {

    transition: all .3s;
}
.grow-on-hover::before {
    content: '';
    background: royalblue;
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    right: 0;
 opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.grow-on-hover:nth-child(odd)::before {
  background-color: gold;
  content: '';
}

.grow-on-hover:hover::before{
  opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

Comment: This will hide the horizontal scrollbar, but the item won't pop out the scrollable div. I want the item to cover the scrollbar on hover

Comment: The vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I added an image

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.scrollable-div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.grow-on-hover {
  width: 210px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.grow-on-hover:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gold;
}

.grow-on-hover:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
  position: fixed;
  width: 178px;
}

.grow-on-hover:hover+div {
  margin-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-div">
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
  <div class="grow-on-hover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working in the way I described in the question

Comment: Okay _ @CristianTraìna